# Can files be recovered from an encrypted linux disk, if it gets formatted to ntfs?

Tags: linux, encryption, system-restore

I sent in my laptop to gateway for a LCD repair, with instructions not to format the hard drive. They saw that I had ubuntu installed and formatted it, installing windows 7. My hard drive was encrypted at the filesystem level. If possible, how do I go about restoring my files?

Answer (score 1):

If you made a copy of the LUKS header, you can try restoring the header, unlocking the partition with the same key, and then using traditional filesystem recovery techniques.

Otherwise, nope.